# Change div opacity when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I would like to have `div` elements fade in and out when scrolling over them by changing the opacity. It sounds really simple but can't get it to work.

The problem I have is that the `div` are in the middle of my page and not on top, so `scrollTop` shouldn't work right?

```js
var fade = $('.b_wrapper');
var range = 400;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  fade.each(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset().top;
    var height = $(this).outerHeight();
    offset = offset + height / 1;
    
    $(this).css({
      'opacity': 1 - (st + offset - range) / range
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  height: 100px;
}

.b_wrapper {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-top: 40px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="b_wrapper">
  <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
<div class="b_wrapper">
  <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
<div class="b_wrapper">
  <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
<div class="b_wrapper">
  <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
<div class="b_wrapper">
  <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
<div class="b_wrapper">
  <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
<div class="b_wrapper">
  <p>this is a div</p>
</div>
```

([JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLnwy6h3/2/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). It watches for changes in the intersection between a target element and its ancestor element or the viewport.

First, create a new observer with options:

```js
let options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

- `root` specifies either the ancestor (containing) element, e.g. with `document.querySelector()`, or the viewport with `null`.
- `threshold` can take an array of intersection thresholds to watch for, which we'll directly use as opacity for our elements. So **each time an element's intersection ratio with the viewport reaches one of these values, the callback is triggered.** (You can use a function here to build the array if you want a more fine-grained sequence and don't want to write everything by hand.)

Next, add each element to the observer:

```js
for (const target of document.querySelectorAll('.b_wrapper')) {
    observer.observe(target);
}
```

The callback is very simple, as we can directly use the provided `intersectionRatio` as opacity. `entries` is an array of all watched elements that you can loop through:

```js
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    entry.target.style.opacity = entry.intersectionRatio
  });
};
```

So much to get you started. Go read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), it's excellent and has many examples.

```js
let callback = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach((entry) => {
    entry.target.style.opacity = entry.intersectionRatio
  });
};

let options = {
  root: null,
  threshold: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]
}
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);

for (const target of document.querySelectorAll('.b_wrapper')) {
    observer.observe(target);
}
```

```css
.b_wrapper{
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
<div class="b_wrapper"><p>this is a div</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best but here is my try :

- On scroll, I check the position of every element to see wich one is the most centered
- On window resize, I update the center of screen value

```js
let centerOfScreen = window.innerHeight / 2;
let pageScroll;
let closestCenteredDivPosition = 999999;
let currentIndex;

let wrappers = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper");
let positions = [];
for (let e of wrappers) {
  positions.push(e.offsetTop + e.offsetHeight / 2);
}

highlightMostCenteredDiv = () => {
  pageScroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
  let currentValue;
  for (let i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
    currentValue = Math.abs(positions[i] - centerOfScreen - pageScroll);
    if (closestCenteredDivPosition > currentValue) {
      closestCenteredDivPosition = currentValue;
      currentIndex = i;
    }
  }
  if (!document.querySelector(".current")) {
    wrappers[currentIndex].classList.add("current");
  } else {
    if (wrappers[currentIndex] != document.querySelector(".current")) {
      document.querySelector(".current").classList.remove("current");
      wrappers[currentIndex].classList.add("current");
    }
  }
  closestCenteredDivPosition = 999999;
}

highlightMostCenteredDiv();

document.addEventListener("scroll", highlightMostCenteredDiv)

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  centerOfScreen = window.innerHeight / 2;
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.current {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```